# A better #define print std::cout<<boost::format

Tags: c++, boost

To quickly insert brief debug statements I would like to turn

`print("%d %d %s") % i % j % str;`

into the more verbose

`std::cout << boost::format("%d %d %s") % i % j % str << std::endl;`

The mentioned `#define print std::cout<<boost::format` does not have the endl, so even if I add a "\n" to the string the buffers are not flushed if a crash occurs on the next line.

The more C++-ish approach to have
`print("string)` return an xPrint instance and overload `xPrint::operator%` does not work because I have no way of knowing when the last `%` call has been made and it is time to print the resulting format string.

Note: I need boost::format, so a printf/fflush won't do, and I'd like the resulting syntax to be brief.

Comment: Is it a mandatory requirement that all of the debug output code is removed by the preprocessor when building in release mode?

Comment: No, there are "proper" macros for that, but since it is a construct like `PRINT_DEBUG(Dbg::Level, string)`, nobody uses it on non-final code.

Comment: `std::cout << boost::format("%d %d %s\n") % i % j % str;` saves enough for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something like

```
#define print(x) std::cout << (x) << std::endl
```

which allows you to do

```
print(boost::format("%s") % str);
```

---

If you really insist on the brief version given above the closest thing I can come up with is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

class Forwarder
{
public:
  Forwarder(const std::string& s)
    : f(s)
  {}

  template <typename T>
  Forwarder& operator%(const T& t)
  {
    f % t;
    return *this;
    // You could even return a reference to f here instead if you wanted
  }

  ~Forwarder()
  {
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
  }

private:
  boost::format f;
};

#define print(x, y) { Forwarder f(x); f % y; }

int main()
{
  std::string str("Hallo");
  int i = 123, j = 456;
  print("%s %d %d", str % i % j);
}
```

---

**EDIT** Here are some more *(potentially dangerous!)* ideas for hacking such a print statement. Code below is just to show the concepts and won't compile as is. Use at your own risk!

**a)** Add a terminating statement to `Forwarder` by adding a specialization for `operator%` instead of using the destructor to trigger printing:

Define helper struct as terminator (better be in a namespace, but you get the idea...):

```
struct END {};
```

Specialize template:

```
template <>
Forwarder& Forwarder::operator%<END>(const END& t)
{
  std::cout << f << std::endl;
  return *this;
}
```

Usage:

```
print("%s %d %d") % str % i % j % END;
```

**b)** Use an operator with less strict binding and right to left associativity. You'd have to introduce a helper type though which could be some kind of logging target.

```
void operator<<=(Logger& l, const Forwarder& f) { ... }
```

Usage:

```
DebugLogger <<= Forwarder("%s %d %d") % str % i % j;
```

**c)** The same as above but using the comma operator (yuck!) which has left to right associativity.

```
void operator,(const Forwarder& f, Logger& l) { ... }
```

Usage:

```
Forwarder("%s %d %d") % str % i % j, DebugLogger;
```

Comment: The use of the destructor to trigger printing is a nice workaround. I wonder if any variation of this can work without the `#define`.

Comment: I don't think that there's another way without sacrificing elegance and/or brevity. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I just added some more ideas to my post. Feel free to elaborate ;)